# Diseñar tabla dinamica con Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Quiero hace una tabla como el de la imagen, pero el problema es que quiero hacerlo con una tabla dinámica, ya que cada sección por ejemplo la de Adultos puede variar el número de celdas dependiendo los pasajeros, al igual que la sección de Niños puede variar también, es por eso que no lo hago con una tabla de tipo estática, entonces la pregunta es:

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer un diseño como el de la imagen usando una tabla dinámica? o a fuerzas tengo que utilizar una tabla estática? pero si uso una tabla estática, ¿como puedo agregarle las celdas de cada sección de manera dinámica?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, es posible. Tienes que usar una `UITableView`, y en el *data source* de la tabla tienes que implementar los métodos `numberOfSections(in:)` y `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`.

En tu caso, la implementación sería esta (obviamente los números tienes que ver de donde sacarlos...):

```
func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (section == 0) ? 3 : 1
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo estoy haciendo con RXSwift, pero con tu respuesta ya me abrió un poco el panorama.

Comment: una cosa mas: tu respuesta es dirigida a una tabla de tipo statica ?

Comment: ¿Qué es una tabla *estática*? Los `UITableView` son dinámicos en el sentido que son el *delegate* y el *data source* que determinan qué elementos se cargan y de qué forma...

Comment: Creo que hay un problema de concepto. Las tablas no tienen que tener siempre el mismo numero de celdas. Eso puede variar en cada momento. Como te dice @MarcosCrispino, en el numberOfRowsInSecion tu le indicas cuantas celdas habrá cada vez que lo necesites para cada sección. En tu ejemplo para la sección 0 tendrás un return de 3 y para la sección 1 tendrás un return de 1. Como lo calcules es otra historia, debería salir de saber cuantos adultos tienes y de cuantos niños tienes

Answer (score 2):

Si lo quieres hacer con tablas dinámicas, tienes que diseñar las `TableViewCell`, y por código debes de indicarle al ***data source*** de la tabla el número de filas que debe de tener por cada sección. Esto lo puedes hacer si tienes en un arreglo del número de pasajeros adultos y niños o de donde tengas esos datos pero debes de indicarlo a la función.

```
func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Puedes usar una variable que tenga el numero de secciones o dejarlo fijo 
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return (section == 0) ? numAdultos.count : numNinos.count
   // igual lo puedes hacer con un if
   /* 
    if section == 0 {
       return numAdultos.count
    } else {
       return numNinos.count
    }
   */
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Aqui puedes validar los elementos que debe de ir en cada seccion de la tabla
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
   if indexPath.section == 0 {
       // TuCeldaPerzonalida : es el nombre de la clase que creaste para tu celda
      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TuCeldaPerzonalida
      cell.nombrePasajero = "Nombre del pasajero Adulto"

    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TuCeldaPerzonalida
        cell.nombrePasajero = "Nombre del pasajero Niño"
    } 
    return cell
}
```